# Else statement isn't showing up

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a school project where people can sell their home and also buy homes. I'm trying to make a "favourite" feature, but the first step isn't working 100%. The first step is to make the heart red if the user has saved a house as favourite if the user didn't save the house as favourite, the heart should be grey.

This is the code I use in the while loop where all houses will return, so $detailsHuis['id'] comes from that while loop.

```
<?php
$huisid = $detailsHuis['id'];
$getFavoriet = "SELECT * FROM favoriet WHERE persoon_id = $gebruikerid AND huis_id = $huisid";
$dataFavoriet = mysqli_query($con, $getFavoriet) or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
<?php while($detailsFavoriet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dataFavoriet)): ?>                   
    <?php if($getFavoriet || mysqli_num_rows($getFavoriet) > 0): ?>
        <span class="favorite" style="margin-top: 0px; color: #f44336;"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="margin-right: 0px;"></i></span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="favorite" style="margin-top: 0px;"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="margin-right: 0px;"></i></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

When mysqli_num_rows is above 0, I see a red heart next to the house information, but when mysqli_num_rows is below 0, I see no heart next to the house information.

$con is created in config.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","kerimbjk","huizenverkoop");

if (!$con) {
    echo "Kan geen verbinding maken met MySQL" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

I would be nice if someone could help me with this problem.

Edit:
Table(favoriet):

```
+--------------------------+
| id | huis_id | persoon_id|
| 1  |   4     |     2     |
| 2  |   6     |     4     |
+--------------------------+
```

Table(huis)(full version: http://prntscr.com/bk5zkl):

```
+------------------------+
| id | prijs | stad      |
| 1  | 146521| Amsterdam |
| 2  | 125932| London    |
+------------------------+
```

Table(persoon):

```
+-----------------------+
| id |username|password |
| 1  | test123|encrypted|
| 2  | demo   |encrypted|
+-----------------------+
```

favoriet means favourite, huis means home, prijs means price, stad means city, persoon means person.

My "house" loop, you can also see the "favourite" loop.
I can't past the whole code for some reason, so here it is: http://pastebin.com/Ld2rqcQX

Comment: When `mysqli_num_rows` is 0, you won't even enter the while

Comment: It helps to run it through a debugger to check what your variables are at any given point in time. But my guess is that since you are using an `or` statement in your `IF[]` clause, `$getFavorite` is never `false`, and you never enter the `else`

Comment: I don't know what to change in my code, could you show me an example?

Comment: I have the impression that you only select favourites in your `SELECT` statement, but you actually need to `SELECT` all houses and outer join that with the favourites. That way you get all houses in the result, which could or could not be favourite. Only then it makes sense to have an `if` to test on that difference. We could help if you would include in your question the structure of your tables in the database and some sample data and desired output.

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope it's enough or shall I also post my while loop where I loop the houses?

Comment: If you loop the houses, then please add that code also, yes. But you should really do this in one query/loop, not two.

Comment: I don't know if you saw my question, but I've added the while loop.

Comment: Which is the SQL statement that results in `$detailsHuis`? It will need to get updated to do it right. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, so that needs fixing too.

Comment: I've added the SQL Statement that results in $detailsHuis on my question. And I've actually never checked if my code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: That SQL can't be right, because you access many other fields from that query, such as `$detailsHuis['afbeelding']`. Where is `afbeelding`, `type`, `id`, ... etc? Please provide the full SQL which you use in your code. In fact you provided SQL for `$overzichtRes`. How is that one used? Does it have anything to do with the question?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I wanted to edit my question fast, so I decided to hide a couple of columns. Is it ok if I post screenshots of my tables?

Comment: Never mind, I am about to post my answer. I suppose you can correct yourself whatever is not really in line with your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- You have a loop on an SQL result set with in it another SQL statement that gets executed, which really is not that efficient. It is better to do it with one SQL statement, and outer join in it the `favoriet` table.
- You apply the CSS class `favorite` whether it is a favourite or not, while you should logically only apply for a favourite. Connected to that: don't put a color style in addition to that. That colour should be defined inside the `favorite` class.
- Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection because you inject `$gebruikersid` inside an SQL string. This is not how you should do it. Instead use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and pass the argument separately.

Here is some untested code you could use for solving the above issues:

```
<?php

$detailsSql = 
    "SELECT   huis.*, favoriet.id AS fav_id 
    FROM      huis
    LEFT JOIN favoriet ON favoriet.huis_id = huis.id
    WHERE     favoriet.persoon_id = ?"; 

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $detailsSql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $gebruikerid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$detailsRes = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

while ($detailsHuis = mysqli_fetch_assoc($detailsRes)): ?>
<div class="item overzicht-item">
    <!-- ... etc ... -->
            <span class="<?php echo $detailsHuis['fav_id'] ? 'favorite' : '' ?>" 
                  style="margin-top: 0px;">
                <i class="fa fa-heart" style="margin-right: 0px;"></i>
            </span>
    <!-- ... etc ... -->
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The `... etc ...` parts can remain like you have it.

Comment: It took a little bit of time, but it works! Thank you for posting the solution.